# Is there an API call to find out the random seed used for the Python `hash()` function?

Tags: python

I know that if the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable is not set or set to `"random"` then the hash function (used for `set`, `frozenset`, and `dict`) is salted with a random number.

So I want to know if it is possible to find out what value is used for a given run of the program.

For context, my Python program generates some output and I want to ensure that it is deterministic for each run of the program. At different points the program iterates over the values in various `set` and `frozenset` objects. For the cases where the order of iteration will effect the generated output I first sort the elements before iterating. But the code is fairly complicated so it is not always obvious which cases need sorting and which cases don't, and I don't want to sort unnecessarily.

So I want to write some unit tests to catch and fix the cases where I need to add a sorted iteration. In order to do this I plan to run the program using `multiprocessing.Process` (in `spawn` mode) where I explicitly set the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable.

But to do this I need determine the seed values that produced the different output for the same input. But I haven't found any documented API that can tell me what random seed was used for a given run of the program.

Comment: note, dicts are ordered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible.

If you do not set `PYTHONHASHSEED`, then Python fills a rather large buffer, `_Py_HashSecret` with random bytes. There are way more than 4 billion possible ways for it to fill this buffer.

`PYTHONHASHSEED` is limited to being a 32-bit integer. It cannot generate all the possible ways that `_Py_HashSecret` can be filled by random bytes.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/41336a72b90634d5ac74a57b6826e4dd6fe78eac/Python/bootstrap_hash.c#L552C1-L552C27

Comment: Thanks for the  comprehensive answer and link to the cpython code.